# JSON.parse with a valid JSON string returns nil in Rack request handler. Same string parses fine outside Rack

Tags: json, ruby, sinatra, rack

My Sinatra server is receiving a JSON string as part of a POST request body. The request body is read and converted to a string like this:

```
request.body.rewind
body_str = request.body.read.force_encoding('utf-8')
```

When I try to convert this string to a Hash using:

```
webhook_hash = JSON.parse(body_str)
logger.info(webhook_hash)
```

`webhook_hash` is nil but the parser does not throw any errors.

I have verified that `body_str` is a valid JSON using the following methods:

- print the string to `STDOUT` and use jsonlint
- save the request body to a file then open the file in a separate ruby script and `JSON.parse`. Running the following with `bundle exec` results in the correct expected JSON:

```
require 'json'
json_from_file = File.read("webhook-body.json")
obj = JSON.parse(json_from_file)
```

I have spent around 3 hours on this and at this point quite frustrated since there are not exceptions being thrown anywhere and I don't know what the cause might be.

I guess the problem has to do with the Sinatra/Rack environment. I am relatively junior regarding things Ruby so any pointers on how to debug or fix this are greatly appreciated!

Comment: What if you `JSON.parse` a static string in the handler? Does it do that correctly?

Comment: ok the problem is solved: the culprit was the logger! `puts webhook_hash` prints out the expected json.  ‍♂️